# How to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} 2^{\frac{xy}{x^2+3y^2}}$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} 2^{\frac{xy}{x^2+3y^2}}$ does not exist?

In other words, how can I solve this: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+3y^2}$?

Comment: You've asked almost 200 questions in over 2 years. Please [edit] your question to include your own thoughts and efforts on the problem, rather than just posting a problem for people to do for you.

Comment: @T.Bongers noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take $x=y$ and $x=2y$ prove both limits are different

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take the polar coordinates to get $$\frac{\rho^{2}\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)}{\rho^{2}\left(\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)+3\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)\right)}=\frac{\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+2\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}.$$ Can you conclude from here?